# Apache httpcomponents-client - CloseableHttpResponse methods not working

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm currently building a very simple `http client` in `Netbeans 8.2` and want to use the `Apache` `httpcomponents-client 4.5` library. It all seemed to be working well until I tried to use a `CloseableHttpResponse` method:

```
System.out.println(response1.getStatusCode());
```

I get a cannot find symbol error and I can't seem to access most of the `CloseableHttpResponse` methods. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;

public class ToDoManager {

    public List<TODO> getAll() throws IOException {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/assignment3_server_13209572/todos");
        CloseableHttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpGet);

        try {
            System.out.println(response1.getStatusCode());
        } finally {
            response1.close();
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Caleb.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it turns out that `httpclient` requires `httpcore` and and `Apache commons-logging` as dependencies. My mistake.